# License error MATLAB R2014a

Tags: matlab

I'm having some troubles installing MATLAB R2014a, getting the following error:

> License error 114.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the The Mathworks:

> This error will occur when the license file used by the license
>   manager has been updated to the new R2014a license file format but the
>   license manager has not been updated to the R2014a license manager
>   version.
>
> To resolve this, upgrade the license manager to the R2014a version on
>   the license server.
>
> This error will also occur when the license file used by the license
>   manager has been updated to the R2013b license file format but the
>   license manager has not been updated to the R2013b license manager
>   version.

For more information about the R2013b license file format change, visit [their FAQ](http://www.mathworks.com/support/faq/network-license-file.html).

If you are unable to upgrade the license manager, [contact Customer Service](http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/) to receive a license file for an older release.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the bin folder from win64/32 to location where you have installed (simply over write).

Then open matlab with run as administrator.

This worked for me.